# Concourse CI shell commands being quoted

Tags: concourse

We are trying to copy multiple jar files in a Concourse CI `package.yml` file as part of a `run` step:

```
run:
  path:
    args:
      - -exc
      - |
        ...
        cp project/target/*.jar build-output/.
```

But Concourse is adding single quotes to the source file, so that it's looking for a file named `'project/target/*.jar'`, and of course it's not finding it.

```
+ cp 'project/target/*.jar' build-output/.  
cp: can't stat 'project/target/*.jar'; no such file or directory
```

I even tried putting double quotes around the jar file name, hoping that it might keep Concourse from changing it, but it made no difference.

We want to use file globbing so that we can use this generically, so that we don't need to know the file names ahead of time. Is there any way we can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre. Try specifying the shell:

```
run:
  path: sh                <== missing `sh` or the shell you have available in the image
    args:
      - -exc
      - |
        ...
        cp project/target/*.jar build-output/    <== no `.`
```

Mhhh, actually maybe the quotes are misleading, there is nothing below `project/target` :-) Try with

```
run:
  path: sh                <== missing `sh` or the shell you have available in the image
    args:
      - -exc
      - |
        ...
        # is anything here ?
        ls -1 project/target
        cp project/target/*.jar build-output/    <== no `.`
```

Comment: We tried breaking out the inline shell script into a bash script file, and it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Was going to suggest that! :)

Answer (score 0):

`set -x` mode quotes all arguments; it doesn't mean that it actually quoted the argument. I think you had a red herring, but I'm glad you got it working.